# Story identification: Alien Abduction, the Perfect Human, read mid 80's in Australia

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the title of a budget science fiction book I read in about
1985. The main theme of the book is a guy is somehow abducted by an alien
ship, his body dismatled cell by cell, then put back together again - but
the reconstructed body is so much better than the original.  He is faster,
stronger, more attractive, smarter - better in everyway, the perfect human.

I'm guessing the book wasn't a best seller, but the concept has stuck with
me over the years and I wouldn't mind reading it again.

Comment: Sounds a little bit like Joseph Delaney's "In the Face of My Enemy".

Comment: HE WAS BORN BEFORE MAN COULD MEASURE TIME--HE WILL LEAD US ALL TO THE STARS.
 
Eighteen thousand years ago a priest ascended a high place, there to hold converse with his gods. That night the gods chose to bless him with their physical reality. Alas, mortal flesh cannot bear the presence of godhead, and so he died.
 
And was reborn. But ever after he was not as other men. He could change his form at will, his wounds healed instantly. . . and he did not age.
 
As millennia passed he grew very wise, and came at last to understand. His destiny lay not among men, but among the stars.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/In-The-Face-Of-Enemy/dp/0671559931

Answer (score 6):

Based upon clues found in @Trevor's answer, I think the title you're looking for is [The Reassembled Man](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2940061-the-reassembled-man) by Herbert D. Kastle. It was published in 1964.

> The Druggish simply disassembled Edward Berner--tissue by tissue, nerve by nerve. In tanks they stored the million remnants and shreds that had been Berner, and they changed his brain into a fantastic recording device. Then they simply put him back together. Sinew by sinew, cell by cell. But it was not the same Edi Berner. The new Ed Berner was stronger, healthier--stronger and healthier than any other man.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too remember reading this book. He could read minds as well. I thought it was called *The Reconstructed Man*. I cannot remember the author.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @JohnO This is definitely an answer. Perhaps not the greatest or most confident one - and maybe not even correct - but it is an answer.

Comment: Nothing shows up on Google or Amazon for that suggested title. While I have little doubt Trevor is familiar with the book, I think the only details he gives are useful for others to narrow down the actual title.

Comment: @trevor I found a short story called [_The Reconstructed Man_](http://phywriter.com/files/docs/stories/The_Reconstructed_Man.pdf) by Johne Cook.  Is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: @NiallC. That link doesn't seem to be good.