# Book where boy is taken apart on alien spaceship

Tags: story-identification

I remember starting a book about 15 years ago where a boy protagonist ends up on an alien spaceship where his body is taken apart (he is eventually reassembled; the aliens are not malicious)...I vividly remember a description of his eyes being outside of his body looking at himself. It sounds strange out of context, but does anyone remember what this is from?

Comment: length of book? juvenile fiction?

Comment: This rings a bell with me. My search brought me to Narabedla Ltd by Frederik Pohl

Comment: Could it be the same story as in [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/story-identification-alien-abduction-the-perfect-human-read-mid-80s-in-austr)?

Answer (score 5):

There is a scene in *My Teacher Glows in the Dark*, book three of the *[My Teacher Is an Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teacher_Is_an_Alien)* series by Bruce Coville, where Peter agrees to let the aliens examine his brain. At one point, he gets woken up and the doctor - who Peter refers to as "CrocDoc" - shows him his own brain in a jar.

See [page 114](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DZwBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP4&ots=hKGqV1RID_&dq=my%20teacher%20glows%20in%20the%20dark%20text&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false). [image: Illustration of CrocDoc holding the brain up]

This scene always stood out to me because, when they put him back together, CrocDoc had casually fixed his nearsightedness, and 10-year-old me was insanely jealous.